# Cannot read property 'people' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hello i created a form and through that form, I succeeded adding data to database but when i am retrieving the data in pug file it is not working.

**Code:**

```
app.use('/update/:productId', (req,res,next)=>{
    const prodId = req.params.productId;
    Trip.findById(prodId).then(products=>{
        console.log(products.name); // I am getting right values here
        console.log(products.people); // I am getting right values here
        res.render('update', {prods:products});
    });
});
```

This is my model.js file, this will help data to get stored in database.

**Model.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const tripSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    people:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    kids:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    days:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    stay1:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    stay2:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    stay3:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    destination:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    departure:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    budget:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        required:true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Trip', tripSchema);
```

**Pug File:**

```
each item in prods 
    h1 #{item.people} //Getting error here
```

Comment: but its giving only this error with findbyid() and working well with find() any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`products` in

```
app.use('/update/:productId', (req,res,next)=>{
    const prodId = req.params.productId;
    Trip.findById(prodId).then(products=>{
        console.log(products.name); // I am getting right values here
        console.log(products.people); // I am getting right values here
        res.render('update', {prods:products});
    });
});
```

is a single product, not an array of products. You could wrap it in an array with

```
res.render('update', {prods:[products]});
```

or directly access the properties

```
h1 #{prods.people}
```

without loop

Comment: it worked but can u help me that why it worked with find() but not with findbyid()

Comment: @MahadAli `find()` returns an array of results. `findById()` returns a single result because an ID is unique.